# jquery accordion - scroll to li header

Tags: jquery, header, html-lists, accordion, scrollto

The accordion is built using lists ul and li  instead of divs.
like most people having this problem the content within some sections of accordion are quite long, when I trigger one of the large headers, the user then scrolls down to see all of the content; underneath that is another li header to click and the accordion closes and opens the last header. With the content in that section also being big the user is left staring at the bottom of the last header section and has to scroll up again.

While researching this problem many people have suggested using the animate() function to focus back on the top of the accordion.
My problem is that because I have used open sourced code I am reluctant to edit it too much, I have tried but no success so far.

Can anyone help? [here is the jquery]

---

```
  (function(jQuery){
     jQuery.fn.extend({  
         accordion: function() {       
            return this.each(function() {

                var $ul = $(this);

                if($ul.data('accordiated'))
                    return false;

                $.each($ul.find('ul, li>div'), function(){
                    $(this).data('accordiated', true);
                    $(this).hide();
                });

                $.each($ul.find('a'), function(){
                    $(this).click(function(e){
                        activate(this);
                        return void(0);
                    });
                });

                var active = (location.hash)?$(this).find('a[href=' + location.hash + ']')[0]:'';

                if(active){
                    activate(active, 'toggle');
                    $(active).parents().show();
                }

                function activate(el,effect){
                    $(el).parent('li').toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').children('ul, div').slideUp('slow');
                    $(el).siblings('ul, div')[(effect || 'slideToggle')]((!effect)?'fast':null);
                }

            });
        } 
    });  
})(jQuery);
```

---

Thank you :)

[EDIT]

I realise you may need the code that triggers the accordion from my html here it is::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul').accordion();

    });
</script>
```

With more research some people suggested a scrollTo() so I tried this aswell::

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('ul').accordion({
    change: function() {
        document.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
        });
    </script>
```

but this didn't work either. "sigh" .. Does anyone know if I'm even on the right track??
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem:

It's a bit of a cheat but this is what I did.

added a scroll class to each of the href links I wanted to click `class="scroll"`

added this script to the page (I put mine under a div called #acc)

```
<script>$(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#acc").offset().top}, 500);
    });
});</script>
```

The only thing I changed from the original is #acc. That is the name of my div surrounding the accordion ul class.

This is where I got the code for the scrolling http://www.sycha.com/jquery-smooth-scrolling-internal-anchor-links

I hope this helps anyone else looking for this problem. ^.^